# Add select control to Angular Material Accordion title or description

Tags: angular, user-interface, select

I have an Angular Material Accordion and I have tried to placed a Material select control in the title area. It will not auto grow to hold the content for the select and also I need to allow selection from the list without the click propagating and opening the accordion. I need this select to allow triggering of a filter in the content for that section of the accordion. How can I get the title or description to hold this content and not scroll the title up and also prevent clicks on the select from triggering open of the accordion.

Comment: Accordion title is meant with a design principle to depict the Summary Title related to the expandable content. If you are attempting a Select control in the title area - to me - it means that there is a different use case. Better to approach this from a UX perspective rather than forcing a Select Control in a well designed Material Component against the standards. - my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I agree in general. However the user in this case needs to be able to quickly know what content is selected within that accordion section while viewing other sections because it indicates what content will be shown. The intent here is to allow at a glance some top level selections.